# Close only the unresponsive split in a Byobu window?

Tags: byobu

I split my byobu window into 3 or 4 splits with either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>. One of these split got hung up because of a bad command I ran. How do I close only this split and not affect the other splits? Currently I have to kill the whole window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd> and start over.

```
byobu --version
byobu version 5.74  
tmux 1.8   
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
```

Comment: This question was answered here: http://superuser.com/questions/712410/how-to-close-window-at-byobu/712614#712614?newreg=d03acffbba1f46728a5967c05680f784

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Holy cow, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd> works. I was stuck with<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> by reading the documents.